# Rowwise and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rowwise

I'd like to sum up three variables in each row. If the variable is NA, then it will be treated as zero. I use dplyr and rowwise but they don't give me the expected result.  Here are my codes and the data sample.

```
a<-tibble(beq=c(7.823,8.962,13.014,6.095,6.482), txditc=c(0.000,0.357,0.651,0.000,0.000),prca=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))

a<-a %>%
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(beq_new = sum(beq, txditc, -prca,na.rm = T))
```

The beq_new gives me the sum of all the rows instead of only one row. I am wondering what is the problem here. Thanks!

Comment: Use `sum(c_across(beq, txditc, prca), na.rm = T)`.

Comment: Another option is `rowSums()`, e.g. `a <- a %>% mutate(beq_new = rowSums(., na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Thanks! In my real data, there are more than three columns. Is there any way I can specify the column names using rowSums?

Comment: Then you can use `sum(c_across(everything()), na.rm = T)`. Inside `c_across` you can use variables in `tidyselect` manner.

Comment: You can specify the index of the columns you want to sum e.g. `a %>% mutate(beq_new = rowSums(.[c(1, 4, 5)], na.rm = TRUE))` for columns 1, 4 and 5, or the names e.g. `a %>% mutate(beq_new = rowSums(.[c("beq", "txditc", "prca")], na.rm = TRUE))`, but the more flexible solution is to use @AnoushiravanR's method and the [tidyselect syntax](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html)

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much, Jared and Anoushiravan!

Comment: `c_across` is not needed here

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `rowwise` with `sum` then:

```
a %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(beq_new = sum(beq, txditc, prca, na.rm = TRUE))
```

```
   beq txditc prca  beq_new
  <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>   <dbl>
1  7.82  0     NA       7.82
2  8.96  0.357 NA       9.32
3 13.0   0.651 NA      13.7 
4  6.10  0     NA       6.10
5  6.48  0     NA       6.48
```

Comment: Hi Tarjae, thanks! I ran the exact same codes as yours, but somehow R gives me beq_new is always 43.4...Do you know what might be the issue?

Comment: Hmmmh. Just start all new. I noticed that you assign `a` to `a`. Maybe after refreshing it should work.

Comment: Thanks! Actually it turns out that my Rstudio version was too old. After I updated the new one, it worked great.